# How to check div background URL with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to check div background URL with condition how to check `if` background URL equal this `default.png` than `alert("please change image");`.

**Edit**

```
<img style="background-image:url('default.png');">
```

Comment: Is it div background you want to check or the image src? Your question and the script snippet are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if( $('img').css('background-image') == 'url(default.png)'){
    alert("Please change image.");
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

To be more simple

**HTML**

```
<img src="default.png">
```

**JS**

```
if($('img').attr('src')=="default.png"){
    alert("please change image");
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/czg5S/1/)**

**--EDIT--**

To answer your edited question

**HTML**

```
<img style="background-image:url('default.png');">
```

**JS**

```
var a = $('img').css('background-image');
var getIndex = a.indexOf('default.png')   //indexOf() is used, for checking the absolute image URLs
if(getIndex!=-1){
    alert("please change image");
}
```

[Updated **Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/czg5S/1/)

Comment: If you include the url() part of the background-image you dont need to check the index. :)

Comment: @wrxsti where your saying to include the url()?

Comment: In the conditional. - if( $('img').css('background-image') == 'url(default.png)')

Comment: what if this `$('img').css('background-image')` returns an absolute path?

Comment: You can still compare to that path. It all depends on the use case I suppose. Depends on if this will be a static function or dynamic. If its dynamic, then your function very well could better suit the issue at hand. :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  var bg = $('#div').css('background-url');//div supposed to be id of div tag

if(bg==$('#img').attr('src'))//img supposed to be id of img tag
  .....
else
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = document.getElementById('my-image');

if(el.style.backgroundImage.indexOf('default') > 0) {
    alert("please change image");
}
```

pure JavaScript